# How do I display files that have a certain property but exempt 1 even though it has that property?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a winform, in my checklist box, i have a select all option. However that item goes under files not deleted, anyone know any code to not show that:

```
if (UnDeletableFiles.Count > 0)
{
   string dmessage = string.Format("File(s) not deleted: {0}", UnDeletableFiles.Count);
   WriteLogMessage(LogFileName, dmessage);
}
```

[image: This is my WinForm which i created. Look out for where it says 'File(s) Not Deleted']

Comment: Check the checkedlistbox selected item is SelectAll or not,to delete the file.

Comment: Why do you have a checkbox for "Select All"? Why don't you just use the button, "Select All" to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in this example you can use this to show correct number of non-existing items

```
if (UnDeletableFiles.Count > 1)
{
string dmessage = string.Format("File(s) not deleted: {0}", UnDeletableFiles.Count-1);
WriteLogMessage(LogFileName, dmessage);
}
```

You are currently showing all contents of the checkbox list, so there will always be "Select all" checkbox

Also to give you another solution to your problem, I need you to provide more code

Comment: That may not work as some people may pick a few files.

Comment: how do i solve this try
          {
            File.Delete(file);
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
            UnDeletableFiles.Add(file);
            string error = string.Format("File cannot be deleted, it is currently open : {0}", file);
            WriteLogMessage(LogFileName, "");
            WriteLogMessage(LogFileName, error);
          }

Comment: this displays 'Select All'

Comment: You should actually use solution of @Roshan . The code he posted for you is to be used when you call 'Delete button click'. Sadly I don't have 50 reputation so I cannot comment on his answer

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
 foreach(object obj in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems )
        {
            if (obj.ToString().Equals("Select All"))
            {
                //dont delete 
            }
            else
            {
                //delete  
            }
        }
```

Comment: im new to programming. What do i put in if n else

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int deletedFilesCount = 0;
        int nonDeleted=0;
        foreach(object obj in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems )
        {



            if (!obj.ToString().Equals("Select All"))
            {
                try
                {
                     System.IO.File.Delete(obj.ToString());
                     deletedFilesCount++;
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {

                    UnDeletableFiles.Add(obj.ToString()); string error = string.Format("File cannot be deleted, it is currently open : {0}", obj.ToString()); 
                    WriteLogMessage(LogFileName, "");
                    WriteLogMessage(LogFileName, error);
                    nonDeleted++;
                }

            }

        }

        //your log
       // deletedFilesCount:
        //nonDeleted
    }
```